# Difference between .RunSynchronously() and GetAwaiter().GetResult()?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm trying to run an asynchronous task synchronously and was wondering what the differences between `.RunSynchronously()` and `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` were.

I've seen a lot of comparisons between `.Wait()` and these two methods, but nothing comparing one with the other.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`RunSyncronously` indicates to run the delegate on the current thread with the current scheduler. However, this applies:

> If the target scheduler does not support running this task on the calling thread, the task will be scheduled for execution on the scheduler, and the calling thread will block until the task has completed execution

`Wait` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on the other hand doesn't schedule a `Task` at all, it simply blocks the calling thread until the task completes. This operation can deadlock if called from a single threaded synchronization context.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321435(v=vs.110).aspx)
and [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: So `RunSyncronously` will never cause a deadlock?

Comment: Wanted to follow up on this (which helped me identify an issue).  You will want to use GetAwaiter().GetResult() if you are using Azure WebJobs or you will see errors around any database command and reader objects when used with multiple workers.  You need to block with WebJobs